# Firebase create Dynamic Link not working in react native iOS. However it seems to work fine in android

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have created a dynamic link using :

```
var link = new firebase.links.DynamicLink(
      "https://freshc.in",
      "frendy.page.link",
    ).android
      .setPackageName("in.frendy.app")
      .ios.setBundleId("in.freshchat.app");
    console.log('link', link); //This is giving the console in both android and ios

    firebase
      .links()
      .createDynamicLink(link)
      .then(url => {
        console.log('Dynamic Link', url); //This is not working in iOS.
        link = "http://" + decodeURIComponent(url);
      });
```

The above code is working fine in android but when we move on to iOS it throws an error that :

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   Error: Failed to create Dynamic Link
>   Error: Failed to create Dynamic Link
>       at createErrorFromErrorData (blob:http://localhost:8081/e76b670d-7fe9-40cb-b837-aa0d40d85769:2122:17)
>       at blob:http://localhost:8081/e76b670d-7fe9-40cb-b837-aa0d40d85769:2074:27
>       at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/e76b670d-7fe9-40cb-b837-aa0d40d85769:2645:18)
>       at blob:http://localhost:8081/e76b670d-7fe9-40cb-b837-aa0d40d85769:2376:18
>       at MessageQueue.__guard (blob:http://localhost:8081/e76b670d-7fe9-40cb-b837-aa0d40d85769:2549:13)
>       at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/e76b670d-7fe9-40cb-b837-aa0d40d85769:2375:14)
>       at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:80:58

Also note that I can open the application when I search from google with the app prefix name like `in.freshachat.app://`
But I don't get the link

What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well well well,
if someone gets this problem remember to add '**HTTPS**' in the domain name :

var link = new firebase.links.DynamicLink(
      "https://freshc.in",
      "https://frendy.page.link",
 )